# N/3 Repeat number linear solution

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, dictionary, time-complexity

"You’re given a read only array of n integers. Find out if any integer occurs more than n/3 times in the array in linear time and constant additional space.
If so, return the integer. If not, return -1.
If there are multiple solutions, return any one"

For the above question I have two answers, Of which one is getting accepted in linear time.

**This one is not getting accepted (partially accepted) TLE**

```
    def repeatedNumber(self, A):
    A=list(A)
    n=len(A)
    b=list(set(A))
    if(len(A)==1 or len(A)==2):
        return A[0]
    if(len(b)==n):
        return(-1)
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if(A.count(b[i])>n//3):
            return b[i]
    return(-1)
```

**This code is getting accepted**

```
    def repeatedNumber(self, A):
    A=list(A)
    n=len(A)
    ck={}
    for i in A:
        if i not in ck:
            ck[i]=1
        else:
            ck[i]+=1
        if(ck[i]>n/3):
            return i
    return(-1)
```

This code is accepted in linear run time. Although the for loop runs n times the time complexity should be O(n).But this got executed in linear time. Can anyone explain ?

Comment: The first runs in quadratic time in the worst case, because `A.count(b[i])` takes time proportional to the length of `A`.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction that you made between O(n) and linear time

Comment: Nether solution is constant space.

Answer (score 0):

The **TC of second code is O(n)** so it is getting accepted. It is O(n) because you are using a Dictionary and average TC of extracting the value for a given key is constant O(1).

The **TC of first code is O(n^2)** not O(n) because the count function in Python has average TC of O(n) and you are using it inside for loop which is again O(n), hence net TC is O(n^2) that's why its not getting accepted

The **Space Complexity is O(n)** for both the solutions.

It is mentioned that you have to solve this question in constant space not linear space.
Your both solutions are of linear space.

**Constant space and Linear time solution is [given here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n3-repeated-number-array-o1-space/)**